# phpunit unit testing error zf2 doctrine

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've just started with Zend framework 2, with Doctrine. I want to set up unit testing for my Album module.

When I run `c:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test > phpunit` from command prompt,
I get following error:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml.d
ist

.FFE

Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 8.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\Serv
iceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entityman
ager.orm_default

C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Service
Manager\ServiceManager.php:452
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:2
5
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php:3
3
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Con
troller\AbstractActionController.php:88
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventMa
nager\EventManager.php:464
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventMa
nager\EventManager.php:208
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Con
troller\AbstractController.php:107
C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerT
est.php:71

--


There were 2 failures:

1) AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testDeleteActionCanBeAccessed
Failed asserting that 302 matches expected 200.

C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerT
est.php:54

2) AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testEditActionCanBeAccessed
Failed asserting that 302 matches expected 200.

C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerT
est.php:64

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 1.
```

The root of the issue seems to be:
**Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\Serv
    iceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entityman
    ager.orm_default** from test..

I don't understand this, please help!

Comment: Are you able to see the webapp? It might be a problem because Doctrine is not installed correctly or not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jurian. Yes the webapp runs fine, and Doctrine is also installed correctly. The add, edit, list and delete functions are working fine with Doctrine for Album module.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay finally got it!!
I changed my TestConfig.php.dist inside module/Album/test to

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Album',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            '../../../config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            'module',
            'vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

so basically just added two missing modules, DoctrineModule and DoctrineORMModule, and the phpunit command showed no errors!

Hope it helps others.

Comment: Thank you!! I have been searching for hours and hours. It finally works!